# Magento middle name required

Tags: magento

How to make middle name required in magento customer entity?

There is option in `System->Configuration->Customer` configuration, but it's optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your Middle Name field Required open the following file:
/app/design/frontend/default/[YOURTHEME]/template/customer/widget/name.phtml

or if it doesn't exist there, open:

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml

Look for the following code:

```
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
```

Where it says class="input-text" make it say class="input-text required-entry"

```
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
```

It's toward the end of the line. Look at the other code in the file as well-- they all have the same class.